# Plugin for CraftBukkit that will allow me to force a user to issue a command

Tags: bukkit

Sometimes I require the need to force a user to type a command. Like when a user successfully donates, I require them to issue a command to open an in-game ticket so our staff can give them the goods they require, however at the moment the user needs to do this manually.

I am looking for an easy to use plugin, with basic "force-a-command" commands. It would be preferable if it came from the [Dev Bukkit](http://dev.bukkit.org) website and worked with version 1.7.2 of Minecraft/Bukkit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Essentials](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Downloads) ([Dev Bukkit link](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/)) has what you need: you can use `/sudo [username] [command] [args]` to force a user to enter a command (or just normal text, if you prefer). I can't find a version for 1.7.2 and I'm no longer sure how the plugin compatibility between sub-versions goes, but there is a release for 1.6.4 and a working [pre-release](http://ci.ess3.net/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt9) for 1.7.4.

Comment: Beat me to it... I run a bukkit server. Essentials is really good.